# Remove Option Tree menu in admin page

Tags: wordpress

I integrated option tree in my template.

I want to hide OptionTree menu item from users. How to remove Option Tree menu item in admin page?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
// Remove Option Tree Settings Menu

add_filter( 'ot_show_pages', '__return_false' );
```

That will remove the Option Tree admin menu.

Comment: Make sure you are adding it after you've included `theme-options.php`.

Comment: I'm adding this code in end of my functions.php, and it's after including theme-options.php, but I have no changes..

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the item you want to remove to your question?

Comment: I've uploaded screenshot

Comment: Thanks, I just tested and saw that my solution didn't work. Testing another one right now.

Comment: @user3724896 I've just tested and found a solution. Please see my previous edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```
function remove_ot_menu () {
remove_menu_page( "ot-settings" ); } add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_ot_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late to the party but since i got to find
a solution (for an old website i restructering) i tought
i might share "a softer" solution.

**2 steps**
1. We ad the current user id to the admin body class
2. We add a css to hide the menu except for the intended user.

**User id in the body class**

```
/*********************************************
** CUSTOM BODY CLASS
*********************************************/
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'custom_admin_body_class');
function custom_admin_body_class($classes){
    $cuserid = get_current_user_id();

    return $classes. 'user-'.$cuserid;
}
```

**Add the desired css to anytype of css loaded to wp-admin**
** replace user-[number] with yours*

```
.wp-admin:not(.user-1) #toplevel_page_ot-settings {display: none;}
```

**If your not loading any css to wp-admin you can use this**

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>.wp-admin:not(.user-1) #toplevel_page_ot-settings {display: none;}</style>';
}
```